# Are knights a worthy investment in Catan's Card Game?

Tags: catan-card-game

I'm still a proud owner of the 1996 Catan Card Game and have two expansions as well. While I like the artwork and the horizontal layout of the game, the gameplay doesn't flow well oftentimes.

One aspect of the game is the knights. Knights are added to your dominion in the same way buildings are added. Every knight has two values one for strength points and one for tournament points These points serve to:

1. Strength points: Compete for the wooden knight figure (worth 1 victory point)
2. Tournament points: Compete for the knight-event on the events-die (equals the 'good year' event but exclusively to the player owning the most tournament points).

From my experience, it may come in handy to invest in an occasional knight just to gain an edge over your opponent, especially early on in the game. But as the game progresses, the rewards of the knights seem rarely to outweigh the costs as knights are not only expensive, they also occupy space needed for buildings. This is even more apparent when playing with the Wizards and Dragons expansion, where the dragons are even more expensive than the knights. So all in all, the competition for knights doesn't seem to span the whole game through.

So my question is: are investments in knights worth it in Catan's Card Game?

Comment: It looks like your second bullet point got cut off